# Python following tutorial but it gives me the error: "(" was not closedPylance

Tags: python

I am trying to make a registration / login form in Python following a tutorial but I get this error with the exact same code.

The code:

```
import hashlib
def signup():
    email = input(“Enter email address: “)
    pwd = input(“Enter password: “)
    conf_pwd = input(“Confirm password: “)    if conf_pwd == pwd:
        enc = conf_pwd.encode()
        hash1 = hashlib.md5(enc).hexdigest()        with open(“credentials.txt”, “w”) as f:
             f.write(email + “\n”)
             f.write(hash1)
        f.close()
        print(“You have registered successfully!”)    else:
        print(“Password is not same as above! \n”)def login():
    email = input(“Enter email: “)
    pwd = input(“Enter password: “)    auth = pwd.encode()
    auth_hash = hashlib.md5(auth).hexdigest()
    with open(“credentials.txt”, “r”) as f:
        stored_email, stored_pwd = f.read().split(“\n”)
    f.close()    if email == stored_email and auth_hash == stored_pwd:
         print(“Logged in Successfully!”)
     else:
         print(“Login failed! \n”)while 1:
    print("********** Login System **********")
    print("1.Signup")
    print("2.Login")
    print("3.Exit")
    ch = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    if ch == 1:
        signup()
    elif ch == 2:
        login()
    elif ch == 3:
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice!")
```

It gives me the error "(" was not closedPylance at this part:

```
email = input(“Enter email address: “)
```

Also, can I use this code to make a registration / login form with easygui in my existing code?:

```
active = True

while active:

    username = enterbox(text2, title)

    menu_choice = choicebox(text, title, menu)

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + menu_choice

    room_choice = choicebox(message, title, rooms)

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + room_choice

    day_choice = choicebox(message, title, days)

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + day_choice

    time_choice = choicebox(message, title, times)

    message = "Geselecteerd: " + time_choice

    active = ynbox("Uw afspraak is bevestigd. Wilt u terug gaan naar het hoofdmenu?", title2, button_text)

    with open("reserveringen.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"Personeelsnummer: {username}\n")
        f.write(f"Vergaderruimte: {room_choice}\n")
        f.write(f"Dag: {day_choice}\n")
        f.write(f"Tijd: {time_choice}\n")

        times.remove(time_choice)
```

Changing the "" but it didn't work.

Comment: Fix the quotation marks: `email = input("Enter email address: ")`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have copied and pasted some code:

[image: wrong quotations]

Anywhere you see these weird looking quotation marks, replace with these:  `"`

i.e The ones next to the `enter` key

Your code is riddled with the weird quotation marks - **you need to replace them all.**

[image: Quotation marks]

#### Note:

And finally, I noticed that you have some weird indentation issues.
In python, indentation matters, so your `if-statement` and `with statement` and `def login():` etc etc and a few other statements, need to be fixed up.